# Can't start worklight server due to ports already in use?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I try to start Worklight server in Worklight 6.2 on mac OS. I keep getting:

`Several ports (10080, 10443) required by Worklight Development Server are already in use`

When I change the port to a different number in the server config, I just get the same error (with the new port).

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Check which apps on your machine use which ports: http://superuser.com/questions/47842/is-there-an-app-for-the-mac-that-shows-you-which-apps-are-using-the-network

Comment: You can also try to kill the Java process.

Comment: `sudo lsof -i :10080` and `sudo lsof -i :10443` yield nothing :-( - is there some better command to use?

Comment: I dunno. Re-install the Worklight Studio? New Eclipse + new installation?

Comment: What flavor of eclipse is best? Luna? Kepler?

Comment: Go for Luna... It's ok.

Comment: I am finding that a few moments after I get the error message, `sudo lsof -i :10080` gives me: 
`COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
eclipse 85287 mobiledeveloper  121u  IPv6 0x94bd44009d5a1551      0t0  TCP new-host.home:51738->new-host.home:amanda (SYN_SENT)`

Comment: What happens when you try in another machine?

Comment: It runs no problem on a windows machine - I think I am just going to switch to that.

Comment: Works great on Mac here; I'm not sure what you're missing... Maybe try in a new User in OS X, might be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run Activity Monitor and search for "java" process. Kill it.

Comment: I don't see any processes called "java"

Answer (score 0):

Try TCPView software  and delete the port number as you mentioned in the above.Then clean project and Run the server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

- Finder -> Go -> Go to folder. Type in the following location /etc
- Search for a file named hosts. Copy it to your desktop.
- Check for a line containing localhost and remove that line, and add a new line as follows: (If no such line is present, no problem add a new line)
  127.0.0.1 localhost
- Save the file and replace the file in /etc.
- Close eclipse and now start the server.

**Note:** Try this only if using *lsof* command or killing the java process didn't solve your problem.

Comment: This helps resolves my issue.  My problem was the machine IP address was changed and the hosts file was not updated.  After I updated the first line which configured the localhost with the machine IP address, MFP server was able to start.  Thanks.